The $\alpha$ particle's energy inside a nucleus is lesser than the Coulomb barrier height. Justify
The $\alpha$-decay is usually explained via quantum tunnelling. This is because the $\alpha$ particles do not have sufficient energy to climb over the Coulomb barrier. But how do we know this?
We can measure the $\alpha$ particle's energy only when it is detected. That energy is indeed much smaller than the Coulomb barrier height. Fine! But how can we be sure that it didn't have higher energy when it was inside the nuclear potential well? One might argue that the forces involved here, nuclear and electromagnetic, are conservative, and therefore, the total energy of the $\alpha$ particle (kinetic plus potential) was always the same, including when it was inside the well.
But even then, how can we exclude the possibility that it had higher energy inside the well, high enough to jump over the barrier, but during the emission process some of that energy is given off as electromagnetic radiation?

Each interaction possibility affects the reaction rate. With emission of gamma or X rays along with alpha particle emission makes the reaction probability and rate too small.

Also, if the alpha particle had enough energy to classically exit the well, it would do so immediately. The concept of a decay rate for alpha particles arises from the quantum, probabilistic nature of the alpha exiting the nucleus.

@Tau307  How could you be sure that it is not doing so immediately? May be as soon as the alpha particle is formed inside, it comes out!
